# Julia prints wrong Pi digits with @printf

Tags: printf, julia, precision, pi

When I compare the output of `@printf("%.50f", pi)` with `BigFloat(pi)` the results are different from 16th places. This might be due to type inversion. But I like to go deeper to understands better what is happening here?

---

Julia> @printf("%.50f", pi)

```
   3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500
```

julia> BigFloat(pi)

```
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062861
```

Comment: 16 sounds like floating point precision vs arbitrary (BigFloat) precision

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pi`, along with several other well-known irrational numbers, have their own special type `Irrational`. These are stored to `Float64` precision, and I don't think there are any plans to change this going into v1.0.

If you want higher precision than that, use `BigFloat(pi)`, as you have done in the question.

But the key point here is that `@printf("%.50f", pi)` does *not* automatically wrap a call to `BigFloat(pi)`. To get that behaviour you would need `@printf("%.50f", BigFloat(pi))`. What you are actually running up against here has nothing to do with `pi` per se, but rather the manner in which floating point numbers are printed in Julia (in fact, in most programming languages). To see what I mean, try:

```
@printf("%.50f", rand())
```

which is essentially asking Julia to print a random `Float64` from the [0,1] interval to 50 decimal places, which is obviously a nonsense request past about 16 decimal places. So why do you get a whole lot of random numbers after the 16th place?

Quickly and accurately printing `Float64` in a nice human-readable format is a topic in its own right. If you are really interested in what is happening, then [this article](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/florian-loitsch/printf.pdf) should get you started, but the simple answer is *don't pay attention to anything after the usual floating point precision*.

Also, AFAIK, this kind of behaviour is common to most programming languages. This is not Julia-specific behaviour you are observing, but rather behaviour at the processor level.